# What's the data structure that can handle random access and key-search?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am working on an online data stream analysis project and I have a very interesting problem:

I need to maintain (at least) a look-up-table, something like `std::map <user_id, user>`, where

```
struct user{
   int user_id;
   bool sex;
   int age;
   double score;
};
```

New users will be freqently added and deleted, using the `user_id` as a key. I guess this is quite easy.

However, I also need to classify the users by sex and age, something like a combined key. The output of the program will ***intensively*** query something like 'give me all the male users who are 34 years old'. Please note that this part is very complexity sensitive.

I took a look at `boost::multi-index` and I found it's like a black box and the templates really confused me.

Is there a way I can tailor a multi-index style data structure just by myself? Anyone knows how to implement it?

Comment: If Boost's multi-index implementation suits your needs (and it sounds like it does) wouldn't it be better to spend time getting more familiar with templates instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Take the time to learn Boost.  There is no point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I would go with a database, atleast an in-memory one if you do not want to persist data.

Comment: thanks guys. I believe boost::multi-index is good. however, it is a general purpose container, right?. I am not sure if there will be any overhead for my specific use-case. As I mentioned, my case is very complexity sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, which do you think is easier?

1) Learn Boost by reading the documentation, searching the internet for examples.

2) Attempting to build your own multi-index class.

When I say easier, I mean easier to (i) program, (ii) maintain, (iii) hand over to a colleague.

Learn Boost! Good luck.

[btw, Boost is often regarded as a testing bed for new features that eventually become part of the C++ standard libraries. For example, `shared_ptr`.]

Answer (score 0):

personally I would build my own data structure; if it's a problem you found online - I think that is the whole point...

here is a idea: since age has a limited range( like 0..100 ),  build a array of pointers `user * database[100]`; use the index to keep the data sorted by age; e.g. dataBase[20] will hold all the users of age 20. 
For all the users of a certain age, you can use a linked list to hold all the users, or build a binary tree and sort them by sex (M to the left, F to the right)..or anything you can think of...

This way, getting the users of age x is O(1)+ O(count).
And even more complex queries about age+sex or age+score become more efficient. Actually worst case scenario is for queries that don't involve age, since you would have to scan all of the array.

Comment: This is poor advice. The OP is working on "an online data stream analysis project." He didn't find the problem online. Rather, he's processing data that's coming in real time. Whereas what you suggest will work, it would take longer to design, code, test, and document than it would to learn how to use an existing solution like boost::multi-index. The other benefit of using Boost is that its solution is probably more reliable and very likely will perform better.